# What gives milk its characteristic white color?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, color

The other day, my kid brother asked me this:

> What pigment gives milk a white color?

Now, I found *that* particular question quite interesting since, as a student of Biology, I already had a rough idea as to what constitutes (cow's) milk: Water, sugars, fats, and a whole bunch of vitamins and minerals. Yet as far as I know, *none* of them play a "pigment"-like role anywhere *else* in nature... which has left me deeply perplexed.

So what pigment is responsible for milk's characteristic white color?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66060/what-gives-fresh-milk-a-yellow-tinge

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is no "pigment" that makes milk white.**

According to Wikipedia:

> A pigment is a material that changes the color of reflected or transmitted light as the result of wavelength-selective **absorption**.

Going by *that* definition of a "pigment", then there is no (white) pigment in milk. In fact (as @Ivan points out in the comments) there is no such thing as a "white pigment", because that would require the "pigment" to absorb **no** visible radiation (if it absorbed **all** visible radiation, it'd appear *black*)

That's because the *real* reason for the white color of milk is a physical phenomenon called *Scattering*. (Source: *Optics*, 4th edition, E. Hecht)

[image]

(Diagram's from Wikipedia)

Milk is an emulsion of fat dispersed as these really tiny droplets in water. These fat globules (and some milk proteins) scatter light of all wavelengths in the visible spectrum. This is why milk appears white

This is the same reason (albeit different *cause*) as to why *clouds* often appear white; except here, the scattering is due to suspended water droplets and dust particles.

Comment: I'd rather stress there is no pigment that makes ***anything*** white.

Comment: Isn't the chief reason for the white color the fact that fats/proteins are imbued with calcium? (homogeneously). Roughly every calcium compound in water renders a white solution.

Note heterogenous milk is a little yellowish, which you would expect as the color of typical fats/oils.

Comment: Nope. Solutions of calcium compounds are mostly colorless. Arguably, there is no such thing as white solution.

Comment: @khaverim http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66060/what-gives-fresh-milk-a-yellow-tinge

Comment: Precipitates in water*, I should have said.

Comment: Scattering by fat doesn't completely explain things by itself, as that would mean that skim (nonfat) milk should be clear, not white. (It's definitely clear*er*, but not completely clear, which implies there's still something else in the milk which is scattering light.)